# Changing a variable with _GET in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the code from [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/01/charts-jquery-ajax/) to display a graph from a single table from a mysql database.

I am trying to update the code to be able to change the table that the graph is reading from. I have added `$tableName =  $_GET['table'];` to "setup.php", so I can add links to the main page to change the table name with `index.php?table=tablename`.

However, I can't seem to set the variable in the ajax.php file. I have tried:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Set up the ORM library
require_once('setup.php');

if (isset($_GET['start']) AND isset($_GET['end']) AND isset($_GET['table'])) {

        $start = $_GET['start'];
        $end = $_GET['end'];
        $data = array();
        $tableName = $_GET['table'];
        // Select the results with Idiorm
        $results = ORM::for_table($tableName)
                ->where_gte('date', $start)
                ->where_lte('date', $end)
                ->order_by_desc('date')
                ->find_array();

        // Build a new array with the data
        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key]['label'] = $value['date'];
                $data[$key]['value'] = $value['vsats'];
        }
                echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Is it not that simple?

EDIT: Worth noting, if I navigate to index.php?table=tablename, and echo $table in the index.php file, it echos correctly "tablename"

Comment: How are you sending the data to this file ? can you show the code ?

Comment: Where is `javascript` part of code?

Comment: try navigating index.php?table=tablename on your browser, if it works, your ajax code is broken, if not your php code is broken, which i doubt.

Comment: The full unedited code can be viewed/downloaded here: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/01/charts-jquery-ajax/

I haven't made any changes to the js code. Also, if I navigate to index.php?table=tablename, and echo $table in the index.php file, it echos correctly "tablename".